# Writing captions on an mp4 video in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, avfoundation, mp4

I have an mp4 video and a metadata xml file which contains information about captions to be added to the mp4. I want to write captions on top of this video in iOS. I got to know this can be done using HTML5's video element. I wanted to know if there any API's in iOS to do it in say, the AVFoundation or MediaPlayer framework.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a hundred percent sure this will answer your question, because it seems kind of vague.
But this might help you out.
http://www.3playmedia.com/2011/12/22/html5-video-captioning-explain-it-to-me/